# CSS stylesheet: style for one button specifically

Tags: html, css

this is my HTML code:

```
<button name='q1.button1' id='q1.button1' onclick='incorrect()' </button>
```

and this is my CSS file:

```
.q1.button1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('images/buttons/q1.button1.jpg');
}
```

i also tried:

```
#q1.button1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('images/buttons/q1.button1.jpg');
}
```

but none of them work, the button is just a big white box!

i thought there could be a problem with the HTML so I tried the following and it worked:

```
Button {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('images/buttons/q1.button1.jpg');
}
```

however, i cant use this because each button has to be different but this will change all buttons

Comment: Escape your dot using `\.`. Dot is used in CSS for classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is not closed properly. The CSS needs a backslash in front of the dot. 3 minutes too slow. @WOUNDEDStevenJones mentioned it in the comments.

```css
#q1\.button1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('images/buttons/q1.button1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<button name='q1.button1' id='q1.button1' onclick='incorrect()'> Cool Button </button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Special characters need to be escaped in CSS:

```
#q1\.button1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('images/buttons/q1.button1.jpg');
}
```

This site will escape them for you https://mothereff.in/css-escapes

FYI, if you want to target the `name` attribute you would have to do this:

```
[name="q1.button1"] {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('images/buttons/q1.button1.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dot from the 'id' attribute

Don't

```
<button name='q1.button1' id='q1.button1' onclick='incorrect()' </button>
```

Try this:

```
<button name='q1.button1' id='q1button1' onclick='incorrect()' </button>
```

Css:

```
#q1button1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('images/buttons/q1.button1.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button has an **id** of "q1.button1", not a class! So, replace the leading dot in your CSS selector by a hash (`#`).

Also, what is messing things up is that you have a dot (`.`) in your ID name, and dots are a special character in CSS to designate class names.

Therefore, either use an ID name without a dot in it, or escape the dot with a backslash (`\`).

```css
#q1\.button1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('images/buttons/q1.button1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<button name='q1.button1' id='q1.button1' onclick='incorrect()'> </button>
```